# Taxonomy Grid Archive Help?

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, terms

I need some help. I would like to make a custom taxonomy archive that shows a grid of the terms(categories) in the taxonomy. I know how to accomplish the grid portion, but I'm having trouble with the main function of displaying the terms. I feel like I've seen this done so many times, but not that I'm trying to accomplish it, I can't.

As an example, [this page](https://www.motifinvesting.com/motifs#catalog=our) shows how I want the taxonomies to look - including title, featured image, post count of terms, etc.

Right now I can't even get the terms to show up as links to the posts within the term. And if I can accomplish that, how do I go about styling the pieces?

I would appreciate some guidance with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve all the terms in a taxonomy, you can make use of [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)

Here is an example from that page to retrieve the term names of a custom taxonomy

```
$terms = get_terms('my_taxonomy', 'hide_empty=0');
 if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     echo "<ul>";
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>";

     }
     echo "</ul>";
 }
```

Here is a list of what is returned by `get_terms` that you can work with

- term_id
- name
- slug
- term_group
- term_taxonomy_id
- taxonomy
- description
- parent
- count

You have to play around with what you exactly need. The only thing is, the link to the terms is not returned, so you'll need to work with [`get_term_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link) to get the link.

Here is an example from that page

```
$terms = get_terms( 'species', 'hide_empty=0' );

echo '<ul>';

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

    // The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

    // If there was an error, continue to the next term.
    if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    // We successfully got a link. Print it out.
    echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

This should kick-start you in achieving your goal

As for styling, this is something that you have to sort out by yourself as this doesn't fall into scope of this site.

Comment: Thank You Pieter! This helps alot. :) :) Great tutorial. Now I just need to apply styles to specific posts.    I found another tutorial that is close, but I'll have to figure how to apply it to taxonomies and not posts :\

Comment: Hi, one more thing. The list only shows the tax terms with posts in them. Is there a way I can also display the empty terms?

Comment: check update. added extra code

Comment: Hi, that doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Should work. Check the codex examples as well. Also, "not working" is broad. What do you mean by not working

Comment: Sorry, implementing the updates showed no changed in terms displayed. Only the terms containing posts show. See code:

`<?php

$terms = get_terms( 'industrygroups' , 'hide_empty=false' );

echo '<div class="row">';

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

    
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

   
    if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
        continue;
    }

       echo '<div class="col-lg-3"><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></div>';
}

echo '</div>';

?>`

Comment: Update 'hide_empty=0' works.

Answer (score 0):

Update... I have gotten the following to work well :)

```
    <?php

$terms = get_terms( 'industrygroups' );

echo '<div class="row">';

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

    // The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

    // If there was an error, continue to the next term.
    if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    // We successfully got a link. Print it out.
    echo '<div class="col-lg-3"><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></div>';
}

echo '</div>';

?>
```